# In views my contextual filter does show the default option of "PHP Code"

Tags: views

In views my contextual filter does show the default option of "PHP Code"

How do I implement this?

thanks
-Sean

Comment: You need to provide more info, what are you using for contextual filter? did you select the `Provide default value` in the `WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL`? Can you provide a screenshot? By default views comes with a `PHP code` option inside the `Provide default value`.

Comment: Do you mean under specify validation criteria? Or are you looking for PHP Code in the list when you first click on Add?

Comment: OK, I using a contextual filter of "content: created year."

Comment: OK, I using a contextual filter of "content: created year."  Here is a screen shot of the issue:: https://www.flickr.com/photos/caillouette/20719797909/in/dateposted-public/   thanks